# Rails time comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, time, comparison

Im trying to validate some user input from a from. Especially Im trying to validate the input from `date_select` and `time_select`. I handle the input like the following:

Input tags of the View:

```
<%= date_select :date, 'date', use_short_month: true %>
<%= time_select :Starttime , 'Starttime', default: Time.now, minute_step: 30,:ignore_date => true %>
```

Convert the input to Time-Object (in the Controller):

```
@Start = Time.new(date['date(1i)'].to_i, date['date(2i)'].to_i, date['date(3i)'].to_i, t_start["Starttime(4i)"].to_i, t_start["Starttime(5i)"].to_i)
```

If I display `@Start` in the View everything is ok! `2013-08-18 16:00:00 +0200`

Now i try to check the time/date for valid input. Therefore i made this function in the controller:

```
def check_date
if @Start < Time.now
  flash[:notice ]= "Booking has to be in the future!"
  return false
else
  return true
end
end
```

But it doesnt work. err_msg. `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass` appears. And i dont know why. The view-output of `Time.now` and `@Start` are the same.

I also tried this with DateTime-object instead of Time-object but the same error appears. Any ideas?

Edit:

Index action:

```
def index
t_start= params[:Starttime]
date= params[:date]
if t_start && date
  @Start = Time.new(date['date(1i)'].to_i, date['date(2i)'].to_i, date['date(3i)'].to_i, t_start["Starttime(4i)"].to_i, t_start["Starttime(5i)"].to_i)
end
check_date
@tables = Table.search(params[:search])
end
```

Thanks

Comment: and how you are calling that function?

Comment: in the index action with `check_date`

Comment: Paste your index method in question as well

Comment: You'll need to post more code so we can see the interaction.

Comment: @RailsGuy I added the index method. Anything else. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by myself... the method call has to be inside the if query otherwise @Start has no value.

Thanks